# How to create a random order of characters with every character and no duplicate without Random class in Java

Tags: java, random, char

is there any other method to create a random order of character java with every character and with out dublicate? like without importing random class

```
 public static String Ra(double jav){

    Random in = new Random();
         String ans = "";
              for (int j = 0; j < jav;) {
                    char x = (char) (in.nextInt(26) + 'A');
                    if(!ans.toString().contains(""+x)){
                        ans = ans +x;
                        j++;
         }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Why avoid importing `Random`? And technically, you don't need to import it to use it. The import is just a shortcut.

Comment: You can add all distinct characters to a collection and then shuffle it.

Comment: You can use `Math.random()` instead of the `Random` class if you prefer. But you need _some_ source of randomness to do something random.

Comment: Ignoring the question of why,  you could use `Collections.shuffle` after making a collection of all the characters needed (..what @JacobG. said..)

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.random(). This will give you a number in the range [0,1).

If you want a random double between a and b (excluding b) do the following

```
double x= Math.random*(b-a)+a;
```

If you want a random double between a and b (including b) do the following

```
double x= Math.random*(b-a+1)+a;
```

If you want a random int between a and b (excluding b) do the following

```
int x= (int)Math.random*(b-a)+a;
```

If you want a random int between a and b (including b) do the following

```
int x= (int)Math.random*(b-a+1)+a;
```

I hope this helps, feel free to ask if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Math.random ()` to get a value from one to 26 and then convert the int to a letter (you could use a `Hashmap`) then check if it is a duplicate...

Comment: *convert the int to a letter (you could use a Hashmap)* I'd rather use the [ASCII Table](http://asciitable.com) i.e. `int N = (int) ('a');